# Graylog Google Pub/Sub output plugin issue

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub, graylog, graylog3

We are building a Graylog output plugin to send data to Google PubSub. This is the code we have written, inspired from the boilerplate code provided by google pubsub ([this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/pubsub/PublisherExample.java) and [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/pubsub/snippets/CreateTopicAndPublishMessages.java))

```
try (InputStream credential = new FileInputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(config.getString(CK_CREDENTIAL_FILE)))) {
                CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider
                        .create(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(credential));
                // endpoint can be set here
                publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

                ByteString finalData = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(String.valueOf(obj));
                PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
                        .setData(finalData)
                        .build();
                ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
                messageIdFutures.add(future);
                ApiFutures.addCallback(
                        future,
                        new ApiFutureCallback<String>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                                if (throwable instanceof ApiException) {
                                    ApiException apiException = ((ApiException) throwable);
                                    // details on the API exception
                                    System.out.println(apiException.getStatusCode().getCode());
                                    System.out.println(apiException.isRetryable());
                                }
                                System.out.println("Error publishing message : " + String.valueOf(obj));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String messageId) {
                                // Once published, returns server-assigned message ids (unique within the topic)
                                System.out.println(messageId);
                            }
                        },
                        MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (publisher != null) {
                try {
                    try {
                        publisher.shutdown();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    publisher.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

On running, we get the following error stack:-

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field io.opencensus.trace.unsafe.
ContextUtils.CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY from class io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:526)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:423)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:90)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:68)
        at org.plugin.PubSubOutput.writeBuffer(PubSubOutput.java:159)
        at org.plugin.PubSubOutput.write(PubSubOutput.java:85)
        at org.graylog2.buffers.processors.OutputBufferProcessor$1.run(OutputBufferProcessor.java:191)
        at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:18
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


 ERROR   [AggregateFuture] - Input Future failed with Error - {}
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field io.opencensus.trace.unsafe.ContextUtils.CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY from class
io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusTracingModule.java:384) ~[g
raylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-ou
tput-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusStatsModule.java:685) ~[graylog
-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-ou
tput-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:81) ~[graylog-plugin-p
ubsub-output-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-ou
tput-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:55)
~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-ou
tput-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:766) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0
-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingManagedChannel.newCall(ForwardingManagedChannel.java:63) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-o
utput-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.newCall(ChannelPool.java:77) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0-SNAPSHO
T.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:88) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0
-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:58) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-out
put-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:64) ~[graylog-plugin-pubs
ub-output-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:81) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0-SNA
PSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:63) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1
.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:41) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1
.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.BatchingCallable.futureCall(BatchingCallable.java:79) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1
.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.
0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87) ~[graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0-S
NAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.publishOutstandingBatch(Publisher.java:317) [graylog-plugin-pubsub-outpu
t-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.publishAllOutstanding(Publisher.java:306) [graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$3.run(Publisher.java:280) [graylog-plugin-pubsub-output-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.j
ar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.j
ava:180) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293
) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field io.opencensus.trace.unsafe.ContextUtils.CONTEXT_SPAN_KEY
from class io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusTracingModule.java:384)
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
        at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusStatsModule.java:685)
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:81)
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:55)
        at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:156)
        at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:766)
        at io.grpc.internal.ForwardingManagedChannel.newCall(ForwardingManagedChannel.java:63)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.newCall(ChannelPool.java:77)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:88)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectCallable.futureCall(GrpcDirectCallable.java:58)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:64)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:81)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:63)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:41)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.BatchingCallable.futureCall(BatchingCallable.java:79)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87)
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.publishOutstandingBatch(Publisher.java:317)
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher.publishAllOutstanding(Publisher.java:306)
        at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.Publisher$3.run(Publisher.java:280)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.j
ava:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293
)
```

We have even looked at the [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java) github repo but can't seem to figure out the problem. We are not using grpc in our communication but we think that it is being used by the google pubsub java module internally.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems like it is related to this change in opencensus, https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-java/pull/1938   can you test with a version before this (pre 0.24.0)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, 
My app is developped with scala (with sbt), but it's the same with maven. 
To solve the issue I change my dependencies with :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-pubsub" % "1.75.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.api-client" % "google-api-client" % "1.30.5"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-core-grpc" % "1.91.3"
```

For the code, just keep default way to create google credential object :

```
def publishMessages(projectId : String, topic : String, event : String): Unit = { 
    val topicName = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topic)
    var publisher : Publisher = null
    val messageIdFutures = new util.ArrayList[ApiFuture[String]]
    try {
      val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(creds)).createScoped(
        java.util.Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")
      )
      publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
        .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build

      val payload = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(event)
      val pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder.setData(payload).build
      val messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage)
      messageIdFutures.add(messageIdFuture)
}
```